# Access to Page's functions from an external class

Tags: c#, wpf

In my project I show a `Window` in this way:

```
MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
mainWindow.Show();
```

than I load a `Page` in its own frame:

```
mainWindow.frame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("PageWelcome.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

`PageWelcome` contains some public functions like this:

```
public void Play()
{
    mediaElement.Play();
}
```

Now from the initial class above, I want to call the `Play` method.
What's the correct approach to do this?
I have to retrieve the current content of the frame?

Comment: Anything wrong with this solution? `((PageWelcome)mainWindow.frame.Content).Play();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either cast the `Content` property of the `Frame` to a `PageWelcome`:

```
PageWelcome page = mainWindow.frame.Content as PageWelcome;
if(page != null)
    page.Play();
```

Or you could just create an instance of the `Page`, keep a reference to it in a field of your class and set the `Frame`'s `Content` property:

```
private WelcomePage page = new WelcomePage();
public void SomeMethod()
{
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow.frame.Content = page;
    mainWindow.Show();
}

private void SomeOtherMethod()
{
    page.Play();
}
```

Using the latter approach you don't have to cast.